# How to handle control's notifications when subclassing a control? Such as EN_CHANGE?

Tags: c, winapi, user-interface

A notification is sent by a control to its parent. When I subclass a control using `SetWindowSubclass`, how can I handle the notifications? I don't want to handle them in the parent's window proc. Is there some thing I can do in subclass proc?

If I subclass a Edit control, how to handle `EN_CHANGE` notification in the subclass?

**Update**

This is the subclass proc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyEditWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
  switch (uMsg)
  {
  default:
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
}
```

I use

```
SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_MYEDIT), MyEditWindowProc, 0, 0);
```

to subclass the Edit control.

But which message should I handle? Certainly not `WM_NOTIFY` because it's handled by the parent.

Comment: If you have already subclassed it, you should be able to handle it in the subclass WndProc. If not, can you post some code?

Comment: @casablanca But which message should I handle?

Comment: Are `EN_CHANGE` etc not all `WM_USER + x`? I haven't subclassed that much, so I can't remember.

Comment: @chris `EN_CHANGE` is a notification code, not a message code.

Comment: Yes, but I thought all of them overlapped. For example, both `EN_CHANGE` and `BN_CLICKED` could be `WM_USER + 1`, as the `WM_USER` range belongs to the window class.

Comment: Ah I misread your question. I don't think you can handle notifications by subclassing. MFC has a feature called [message reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) that does this but nothing in the Win32 API that I know of does this.

Comment: @chris `EN_CHANGE` is 0x0300, and `WM_CUT` is also 0x0300, they are not same thing.

Comment: @casablanca But MFC is also calling Win32 APIs, How does MFC do that?

Comment: @EFanZh, Ah, `WM_USER` is 0x0400, so that can't be the case then. Now I wonder what it was that does that.

Comment: @EFanZh: It's actually handled internally by MFC -- the message is processed by the parent, but MFC "reflects" the message by calling a handler in the child class.

Comment: @casablanca So there is no way I can do this, unless I simulate the message reflection thing manually.

Comment: While EN_CHANGE has the same value as WM_CUT, there's no danger of confusion as the EN_ values are *NOT* message values; instead they are the value of the HIWORD(wParam) in a WM_COMMAND message.

Comment: @EFanZh: At least I don't know of a way. You might want to wait and see if someone else comes up with a clever solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I subclass a Edit control, how to handle EN_CHANGE notification in the subclass?

Short answer: you can't. If you subclass an edit, you only get to see the messages sent *to* it; you don't get to listen to or intercept the messages already sent *by* it (although you can add additional outgoing messages).

If you do need to do this, however, an alternative technique might be to create an intermediate window that *wraps* the edit, so that the original parent dialog has your wrapper as the child, and your wrapper has the edit as the child. Now your wrapper is positioned to intercept and filter messages going in either direction.

It will have to take care to manually forward all relevant messages, and handle resizing and other housekeeping issues; you get a bunch of that 'for free' with subclassing, but have to deal with it explicitly when wrapping. Also, since mouse/keyboard input will still go to the inner control; if you need to listen in on that, then subclassing will be necessary *in addition* to wrapping.

Comment: +1 for an interesting solution, even though it might be a pain to implement.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no straightforward solution to this using just the Win32 API. Subclassing lets you process messages **sent to** a control, not **sent by** the control. Win32 notifications are sent by a control directly to the parent and I don't think you can change this behaviour.

MFC does something similar to what you want through a feature called [message reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) -- the message is still sent to the parent window, but the parent looks for "reflection" handlers in the child window and manually calls these handlers.

You can write something similar to MFC reflection yourself, but it's going to take some effort, so if there's an easier alternative, you should go with that.

Comment: Borland/codeGear/Embarcadero's VCL does something similar. WM_COMMAND, WM_NOTIFY, and other child-sent messages are caught by a parent window and forwarded to the child that sent them so child classes to process their own messages.

Answer (score 2):

EN_CHANGE and the like are always sent to the parent window. You can't handle them in the sub-classed control because they aren't sent to the control, they're sent to the parent.

If you're looking for a way to do a self-contained sub-class of an edit control without having to add code to the parent's window procedure, and you want to handle those notification messages, the only way would be to sub-class the parent window as well.

Comment: Or use a local message hook via SetWindowsHookEx() instead, looking for messages that are destined for the parent window. As long as the hook process is in the same process as the window, you don't need to put the hook in a separate DLL.